# Using a self-hosted Video as BG. Can i control play/pause by clicking on the video, like embedded YouTube video has?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video

I am working on a One-page WordPress site and using [Muffin Builder](http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/features/dragdrop-muffin-builder/) for layout. I am using its feature where i can set a self-hosted video as BG. However, there is no option to control the play/pause of the video. I need help in adding some custom JS to make the video play/pause on a click. Possible?

Link : http://flipped.in/AXSuede/

The video BG is the first section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

When handling your click event, get your video using :

```
var myVideo = document.querySelector('#myVideo'); //must be a MediaElement like <video> or <audio>
```

Then, pause or play it :

```
myVideo.play();
myVideo.pause();
```

To stop it, you have to manually set the cursor to the beginning :

```
myVideo.pause();
myVideo.currentTime = 0; //Set the cursor to 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this jquery code

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($) {
        $('video').addClass('is_playing');
        $(document).on('click', '.section_video', function(){
            var $video = $(this).find('video');

            if($video.hasClass('is_playing')){
                $video.get(0).pause();
                $video.removeClass('is_playing').addClass('is_paused');
            } else {
                $video.removeClass('is_paused').addClass('is_playing')
                $video.get(0).play();
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
<script>
```

didn't try it but should work.

greetings timotheus

Comment: Hi Timotheus. Thank you for the response. I added this in the Custom JS field in theme settings. However, it did not help. Can you please suggest some changes here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i don't know if that field uses jquery library too. cant you just open your header.php file in theme directory and insert that snipped between an open <script> and closing </script> tag? i updated the code so you just can copy all of that in your header php. between your head tags

Comment: Hey. Thanks for that. I have added the code in the <head>. However, it still does not work. Sorry to bug you again and again. I feel am this close :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have element with an higher `z-index` over your video element, the click events will be blocked.

One solution to check if the click event happened on the video element is to get its [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) values and compare them with the event's `clientX` and `clientY` properties.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var vid = document.querySelector('video');
    // get the video position in viewport
    var rect = vid.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Did we clicked over the video ?
    if(e.clientY > rect.top && e.clientY < rect.top + rect.height)
       // is our video already paused?
       vid.paused? vid.play(): vid.pause();
}, false);
```

Comment: Hi Kaiido. Thank you for the answer, i removed it altogether!

Comment: Huh? You removed what? The video? I still can see it in the linked page. Or was it a different one when you asked the question?

Comment: Hey. No, i meant the element (text box) with higher z-index on top of the video. But, the clicks are still not working.

Comment: Yes, because there is still a section-wrapper and a `.mask` over it. Note that if you do remove this later, the controls will be shown on mousemove of the video. Did you tried the solution in this answer? No need to remove anything

Comment: Yes, i added this code in the <head> between <script> tags but did not work.

Comment: You have to wait for the page has loaded, nest it in a document.addEventListener('load') or add it in `<script>` at the bottom of the page